# chromium browser when opening html file through command line

Tags: javascript, browser, command-line, chromium-embedded

When I open a html file via the command line: `chromium-browser "file://myhtmlfile.html"`, the file opens and appears correctly, however, a simple slider control on the page does not behave as expected. (It does not react to touch screen correctly.)

If I then open another tab in the same chromium window, and navigate to the same file and open it in the second tab, it behaves as expected.

When using the dev tools, I don't see any differences. The browser is not loading the file into the browser in the same manner.

Does anyone have a good explanation for this?

Thanks